# Argand Diagram Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

The following question is given:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmg6z.jpg)

This is my answer:
[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsF8l.jpg)

I am not sure I have done it right, can you please advice,
Thank you.

Comment: Yes this is correct. For such small solution-verifications I recommend asking them in [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics).

Comment: @vitamind Thank you!